# How read array from a file

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

im trying to create a matrix from a file, the file is like this: 
Where my first line has the size of the matrix= 10 x 9
And in the other lines, we have 15 values distributed aleatory.

```
3 5
4 5 6
12 34 12 12 8
34 23
12 34 34 10 89
```

With the info size i will define my matriz. I use this method for read:

```
public static void read(){
    String line= "";
    int i = 0;
    try {
        while((line = bf.readLine()) != null){
            if (i == 0){
                //Call method that get the size and create my global matriz
            }else{
                String[] list = line.split(" ");
                //I need help here, for insert correctly in the array 
            }
         i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How i can do for insert orderly in the matrix? My matrix should be like:

```
    4   5   6   12  34 
    12  12  8   34  23
    12  34  34  10  89
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
String input = "3 5\n" +
               "4 5 6\n" +
               "12 34 12 12 8\n" +
               "34 23\n" +
               "12 34 34 10 89\n";
Scanner in = new Scanner(input);
final int rows = in.nextInt();
final int cols = in.nextInt();
int[][] matrix = new int[rows][cols];
int row = 0, col = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
    matrix[row][col] = in.nextInt();
    if (++col == cols) {
        row++;
        col = 0;
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
```

Output:

```
[[4, 5, 6, 12, 34], [12, 12, 8, 34, 23], [12, 34, 34, 10, 89]]
```

It is not necessarily the best way to do it, but I wanted to show the manual increment logic of `col` and `row`, where `row` is incremented when `col` rolls over.

Using [answer by sebenalern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37221075/5221149), it'd work like this:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[rows][cols];
for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        matrix[row][col] = in.nextInt();
```

Using [answer by Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37221063/5221149), it'd work like this:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[rows][cols];
for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
    matrix[i / 5][i % 5] = in.nextInt();
```

All 3 versions rely on the `Scanner` to simply provide all the values in a sequence, regardless of how they were put together on lines.

If you don't want to use `Scanner` (e.g. because it is slow), and read the input line-by-line, then values on a line, the 1st version would be easier to use. Otherwise the 3rd is the shortest, and the 2nd version is the most straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint - I'll leave your homework to you - :
In this case it would be pretty simple to maintain a counter of all values that have been read so far, and map each of these counter-values to a matrix-value like this:

```
0 = (0 , 0)
1 = (1 , 0)
...
5 = (0 , 1)
6 = (1 , 1)
...
```

Using something like this:

```
int row = counter / rowLength;
int col = counter % rowLength;
```

In your case:

```
matrix[counter/5][counter%5] = someValue;
```